# Chrome unresponsive during loop in MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, google-chrome

I have a view that simply populates the page with objects from a list in my model, but during this, Google Chrome becomes unresponsive and asks whether we want to kill the pages. This is a bit frustrating as IE and FF both work fine (loads instantaneously) and I am not about to start recommending users use IE as a short-term solution (just can't bring myself to do it).

Here is an example of where the page is dying. The loop is populating rows in a table:

```
For i = 0 To Model.ListOfStuff.Count - 1
    @<tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(Function(d) d.ListOfStuff(i).SelectedItem, Model.ListOfStuff(i).Name)</td>
    <td>
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(Function(c) c.ListOfStuff(i).SelectedItem)
        @Html.HiddenFor(Function(c) c.ListOfStuff(i).Id)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Next

This contains no more than 900 records, so I'm not sure why Chrome is falling over at this.

So my question to SO, is, how do I optimise this so that Chrome does not fall over? OR, is there a known work around for Chrome becoming unresponsive? I'm clutching at straws here.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: That code will be executed on the server side. If Chrome is becoming unresponsive its unlikely to be this. Do you have some Javascript running elsewhere?

Comment: lil confuse here. Could you change code to use 'foreach' instead of 'for' and try?

Comment: @ChrisRedhead : That's what was confusing me, but without the loop, the page loads instantly, so I'm wondering if it's not a code issue and quite likely to be a Chrome issue. There is no JavaScript running on the page, aside from a simple update element script that runs once (I added debug lines to check).

Comment: @Savaratkar : Good idea, I just tried this, but when doing a foreach you lose your direct reference to the Model list objects, so it breaks the persisting of values. That appears to be why this was done in a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles across this and is in a similar position, here is the solution to the problem.

The problem was that I was including jquery-1.7.1.js in my shared _Layout.vbhtml view, in a bundle. For some reason, although no jQuery was actively being called, this caused multiple views to crash if they included loops with quite a few records in them.

To fix this, I created a new shared layout view called "_LayoutNoScripts.vbhtml" (and removed all scripts) and set the problematic view's Layout to this instead:

```
@Code
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutNoScripts.vbhtml"
@End Code
```

Then, because jQuery was actually needed in the view, I included the script as an individual reference:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")"></script>
```